# GridView not taking full screen

Tags: android, gridview

I have an android `GridView` which is stacked between multiple `TextView` but the problem is `GridView` is not taking the complete screen it's just extending by the size of the first row of `GridView`. Whatever I do `match_parent` or `wrap_content` but when I am giving it prefix size it's got extended in that size.
So what can I do to extend it in full screen?

This is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/b_white">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_grey">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ambilwarna_arrow_down"
            android:onClick="nNonClick"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="@color/l_blue"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ambilwarna_arrow_down"
            android:onClick="sNonClick"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ambilwarna_arrow_down"
            android:onClick="bNonClick"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ambilwarna_arrow_down"
            android:onClick="pNonClick"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ambilwarna_arrow_down"
            android:onClick="p2NonClick"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the reference to how it looks [match_parent look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOO81.png). And This is how I want [height 500dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H48iZ.png).

My row item in `GridView` is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/general"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/b_white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/design"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ovel"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/frame"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/d_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/b_white"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="@string/l_general"
            android:textColor="@color/f_black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have try with `wrap_content` to `RelativeLayout ` which is parent of `<GridView>` with id `rl1`

Comment: nope, didn't work.

Comment: why do you have a gridview inside scrollview?? Also I suggest moving into recyclerview with GridLayoutManager. if it is so necessary to have a grid inside a scroll, then use a nestedscrollview with a recyclerview instead of a gridview

Comment: When I was using a nested scroll view the scrolling gets disabled in the grid view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` in your gridview

Answer (score -1):

**Try to use android:stretchMode="columnWidth" inside GridView**

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@color/l_blue"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your gridview row item_view.xml. Use NestedScrollView beside ScrollView.